# knife tool not ending

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, knife-tool

I'm just starting to use the knife tool and, after I finish using the knike tool, I can't seem to get it off of the knife tool. How do I get it off of the knife tool?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to quit the *Knife* modal.

Comment: LOL, thanks. I guess I forgot to mark a question as read so since you gave me the true, correct answer, I'll mark yours!

Answer (score 1):

If you selected the knife tool in the sidebar on the left, you can just select a new tool (Select Box, the top one, is the default):

[image: h]

Here, the knife tool is selected, so any time you click, it will use the knife. Just select the first box, and it will go back to the default.

Personally, I just use the knife tool by pressing k, and then after i press space to end the cutting, it will automatically go back to normal mode.

Comment: Thank you! I was confused bc I was using K and I couldn't figure out how to get off.